# Create a User Access Matrix in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am looking for a way to set up who can see what in my database.

I have a table of users.
Each user will be interested in some of the other users.

Example:

```
Adam
Beatrice
Charles
Diana
```

Here's the functionality I'm looking for:

- Let's say I am Adam.
- I go to settings (which can be a form) and enter "Adam".
- A list of all users (including Adam) is shown with a checkbox before each.
- I select which other users I want to follow.

One idea would be to create a column named for each user in the user-table.
So as a new user is added a new column is added - effectively a matrix.

This is where I need your help. Since what I am looking for is an "Access matrix" it is difficult to find solutions that implement this in MS Access.

Comment: You are looking for a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) aka many-to-many relation. With the tables on both sides being the same (users).

Comment: This gets me a bit on the way. When I search for tutorials the format is usually how to tie multiple products to orders. I can't seem to find an example where I connect a table to itself, letting a user select multiple users.